# In Shiny/R why my lis with purrr::map()t is not working in module?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

This is my module file:

```
library(semantic.dashboard)

example_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(

    # 1:5 %>% map(~ list(menu = list(paste0(.x)),
    #                    content =list(paste0(.x))))

      list(menu = list('B'),
                content = list('B')),
    list(menu = list('C'),
         content = list('C')),
    list(menu = list('A'),
         content = list('A')),
    list(menu = list('A'),
         content = list('A')),
    list(menu = list('A'),
         content = list('A'))

  )
}

example_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

    }
  )
}
```

When I run the code without using the purrr::map() function the panels labels are created well.

But when I try to create the panel labels with purrr::map() function it is not created

Bellow Is my shiny App

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(color = "blue"),
  dashboardSidebar(side = "left", size = "thin", color = "teal",
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem(tabName = "tab1", "Tab 1"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(

    tabItem(tabName = "tab1",

            tabBox(
              collapsible = FALSE,
              title = "Pull",
              color = "black",
              width = 16,

              tabs = example_UI('question')
              )

            )))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map()` function returns a `list()` of length 5. It does not return five separate lists like you are using when calling `tagList()` without the map. In order to expand that single list into different paraemters, you can use `!!!`. For example

```
tagList(
  !!!(1:5 %>% map(~ list(menu = list(paste0(.x)),
                     content =list(paste0(.x))))
))
```

Comment: thanks for your time! The do.call solution is amazing. The !!! I have to have a better understanding. Thanks again!